# Reducing a number on each iteration until it reaches exactly 0

Tags: javascript

I want to reduce n to 0 on the last iteration but my calculations are wrong. Im overlooking something. Right now im doing Math.round(n / loops). I need to find a way to disperse the substraction in such a way so that in the last iteration n becomes 0 while the range between each n´s is constant.

```
function check(a, b) {
        let loops = a / b;
      let n = 200;

      for (let i = 0; i <= loops; i++) {
        console.log(n);
        n -= Math.round(200 / loops);
      }
}

check(60, 10)
```

Edit: Im sorry but these downvotes are ridiculous.

Comment: Why do you believe that will always reach exactly zero?

Comment: @vlaz exactly thats the point. I want it to reach 0 by somehow filling in the missing substraction but disperse it evenly on each iteration.

Comment: Have you tried working it out by hand?

Comment: Take `check(3,2)` as example, it will need less paper.

Comment: learn to use debugging tools instead of guessing

Comment: @charlietfl seriously? I know how to debug.

Comment: Then you should probably realise that your code is fine - it's doing exactly what you've told it to. Your math is off, however.

Comment: @vlaz I edited my question. Exactly thats the issue

Comment: As it is, your math doesn't always go to zero, like in the specific case: https://eval.in/649660

Comment: @sal I have no idea why the hell this happened to me. I wonder if its due to the fact that I was programming the entire sunday without breaks. After a time you stop being sensible towards the easiest problems.

Comment: @Asperger, it happens to the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that the expression `n / loop` is different in each iteration. You might have intended that this expression was constant, in which case the logic would have been more reasonable.

Use a separate variable that starts with the value of `n` and then is the subject of the subtractions, but *without* changing the original value of *n* that is used in the expression `n / loop`:

```js
function check(a, b) {
    let loops = a / b;
    let n = 200; // don't change n after this.
    let n2 = n; // use a separate variable for that.
    for (let i = 0; i <= loops; i++) {
        console.log(Math.round(n2)); // only round in output
        n2 -= n / loops; // use n, but only change n2
    }
}

check(60,10);
```

Comment: Originally I had n -= 200 / loops. I should have copied the entire code instead of writing it new (I love writing xd).  I still got the wrong result though but I noticed you rounded the result. Darn, I totally forgot to do so. You are right, it rounds the negative result up to 0.

Comment: I really need to take breaks after extremely long coding sessions.